# Stop/Remove Inserting NULL as default in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, model, sqlalchemy

I have the following columns in SQLAlchemy:

```
name = Column(String(36))
uuid= Column(String(36))
```

Sample Insertion query:

```
new_request = Project(name = names)
db_session.add(new_request)
db_session.commit()
```

I already set default value for uuid in database.

But SQLAlchemy set uuid=None in query, so default value is not generating.

How to avoid default null insertion.

Answer (score 2):

One of possible ways is using builtin [`UUIDType`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid):

```
your_column = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True)
```

---

A custom *uuid* generators are also acceptable via `default=...` and `server_default=...` arguments of `Column` type.

With `server_default=...` you are able to specify a *UUID* generator function typical for a certain database engine (like `gen_random_uuid()` for PostgreSQL).

Comment: Thanks.. I fixed it by giving empty string as default..'uuid = Column(String(36), server_default=text(""))'